# Related smart pointers sharing a reference count

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a section of C++ `Qt` code that receives a network message and decodes it into a Google protobuf that is managed by a smart pointer.  The function does some minimal structural parsing of the protobuf to see if optional message fields are present, dispatching signals if certain pieces of the message are present.

Currently, those signals contain copies of the smart pointer that contains the entire message, taking advantage of reference counting.  However, I'd like to dispatch smart pointers to specific sections of the message so that the downstream handlers don't need to re-parse the entire protobuf.  I cannot simply create a new smart pointer to the relevant message section because it will try to free that section when the the new pointer goes out of scope.

An attempt at illustrating this, omitting some safety checks:

```
void Interface::processProtobuf(QByteArray const & networkData) {

    QSharedPointer<proto_message> msg(new proto_message);

    msg->ParseFromArray(networkData.data(), networkData.length());

    if (msg->has_configuration()) {

        // This will eventually attempt to free, thus causing corruption
        // of msg.
        QSharedPointer<config_message> cfg(msg->mutable_configuration());
        emit configurationChanged(cfg);

        // I resorted to this, which forces the receiver to re-parse
        // the data structure (which might be expensive for a deeply-nested
        // message) to get the desired 'configuration' pointer.
        emit configurationChanged(msg);
    }
}
```

Do do this, I really need a way to create a "related" sub-pointer that inherits (and increments) the reference count on the parent pointer so that the data destructor isn't invoked until all the subs and the parent are out of scope.  Is this functionality available in one of the standard smart pointer implementations, or have I created an unnecessary special case?  The closest thing I've found is `Qt`'s `QSharedDataPointer<>`, but I don't think it helps in the case of creating a sub-pointer.

`Qt` solutions aren't necessary.  This was more of an academic question, as my workaround will be fine for my current case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr` if you don't have C++11) has a constructor which takes a shared pointer `r` and a pointer `p`. The constructed shared pointer will point to `*p`, but *share ownership* with `r`. This should be what you need.

The constructor's signature is

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *p) noexcept;
```

Comment: Yep.  That's what I needed.  I didn't dig deep enough to find that signature.  Thanks.